Execute Argo workflows with user-assigned managed identity
I try to access my blob storage from Argo workflow by this flag: "useSDKCreds: true" (see here: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/main/docs/configure-artifact-repository.md)
For that I set up a ServiceAccount where the following annotation was set:
"azure.workload.identity/client-id: xy"
In the user-assigned managed identity I configured the Federated Credentials as well connection to this given ServiceAccount.
In AKS I enabled the use of user-assigned managed identity following this docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity
But I still get the following error message when I try to reach the blob storage:
"DefaultAzureCredential: failed to acquire a token. Attempted credentials: EnvironmentCredential: missing environment variable AZURE_TENANT_ID ManagedIdentityCredential: no default identity is assigned to this resource AzureCLICredential: fork/exec /bin/sh: no such file or directory"
What do I miss?
Thanks a lot!

AZURE_TENANT_ID is an environment variable that is relied upon in Azure Go SDKs which interact with Azure resources, such as Blob Storage.
When you set useSDKCreds: true, your workflow is able to read the configured service account's client ID and secret, via the DefaultAzureCredential class. However, to obtain a token for authorisation against other resources the runtime has to authenticate with the MS identity server. For this, the tenant ID is essential so that MS can authenticate the principal against the correct tenant or directory.
You'll find your tenant ID in Entra ID / Active Directory, among other places.
You need to set the AZURE_TENANT_ID environment variable in any container which relies on it, or at the pod level.
env:
  - name: AZURE_TENANT_ID
    value: "<YourTenantIdGUID>"


I have tried this before.
There seems to be an issue with the Argo, because providing this env variable doesn't help. It looks like that Argo doesn't go through each authentication possibilities (DefaultAzureCredential, EnvironmentCredential,ManagedIdentityCredential). Even if I set each environment variable, it doesn't see those. Whereas the ManagedIdentityCredential should be provided. So my assumption is that after the DefaultAzureCredential failing, it fails.

@LászlóMarton OK. Is there a particular reason you decided to use a user-drfined service account, instead of a system managed one?
